# Images are being appended twice in Masonry

Tags: jquery, plugins, append, jquery-masonry

I've encounter a strange problem with Masonry. I'm using infinite scroll and when the images are loaded they are being appended twice. I noticed the problem today after adding more pages. I'm really unsure what is causing it but figure it has to do with my jQuery code. My code is below.

```
(function(){

//masonry
$(function() {
    var container = document.querySelector('.post_container');
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        // options
        itemSelector: '.post'
    });
});

//images loaded
var $container = $('.post_container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.post'

    });
});

$('.container').infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "div.pagination",
        // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector : "#next a",
        // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : '.post',
        // selector for all items you'll retrieve

        loading: {
            finished: undefined,
            finishedMsg: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>",
            msg: null,
            msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>",
            selector: null,
            speed: 'fast',
            start: undefined
        }
    }, //callback to make the all work together
    function(newitems) {
        $container.append(newitems);
        imagesLoaded(newitems, function(){
            $container.masonry('appended', newitems);
            $container.masonry('layout');
        });
    });
```

I've doubled checked my html and even went as far as to delete it and check each image one at a time. For some reason the plugin is appending the images twice.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with this

```
function(newitems) {
    $container.append(newitems);  // appending the same thing
    imagesLoaded(newitems, function(){
        $container.masonry('appended', newitems); // appending the same thing
        $container.masonry('layout');
    });
});
```

I'm not familiar with masonry, but maybe this is why it's appending twice.

Comment: No it's necessary if I don't have that it'll break the function.